# Is it possible to convert DQL query builder to query builder?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I have a tree structure, it is managed by `Gedmo\Tree`. I want to make complex update for one field in subtree, this update requires join with another table, it is not supported by DQL. So I want to get DQL builder by `Gedmo\Tree` repository method `childrenQueryBuilder`, convert it to `QueryBuilder` and add update statement.

```
$dqlQueryBuilder = $repository->childrenQueryBuilder($node, ...);
$dqlQueryBuilder->resetDQLParts(['select', 'orderBy']);
$queryBuilder = convert($dqlQueryBuilder);
$queryBuilder->leftJoin('...', 'lj');
$queryBuilder->update('node.update', 'concat(node.field, lj.field)');
```

I know that I can write custom `QueryBuilder`, I just wonder if such conversions  are possible by doctrine builtin tools or some 3-rd party libraries.

Comment: Are you able to post the DQL? Or maybe a simplified version of it?

Comment: Yes, I updated OP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no such thing as SQLQueryBuilder in Doctrine, there's only `QueryBuilder` which is an DQL Query Builder. What you can do is to convert `DQL` to `SQL` by doing

```
$stringSql = $queryBuilder->getQuery()
    ->getSQL();
```

Once you have it you might play with native sql and then execute it as a raw sql.

Note: I'm not sure what exact *DB Specific statement* you mean, but there's a possibility to map DB Specific functions to DQL by making use of `FunctionNode` class. Once you have your function mapped to DQL you might accomplish it with DQL only.

Check [documentation](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/cookbook/dql-user-defined-functions.html) on how to work with custom DB functions in DQL

Comment: I didn't pose correct about SQL query builder. SQL query builder = `\Doctrine\DBAL\Query\QueryBuilder` https://github.com/doctrine/dbal/blob/master/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Query/QueryBuilder.php